# Ansible: How make select sub list of list

Tags: ansible

I have a list of files (with full path).
How can I select only files that match a pattern?

for example I have:

```
/tmp/test/a.txt
/tmp/test/b.txt
/tmp/test/c.log
/tmp/test/d.log
/tmp/test/e.txt
```

and I want to get only files end with log

```
/tmp/test/c.log
/tmp/test/d.log
```

i think my list does not work with your example

here is my script and its output

```
- name: List all files 
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
      verbosity: 3
    with_items: "{{ valid_logs_dir_files.stdout_lines }}"
```

will print

```
changed: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/a.txt)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/b.txt)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/c.log)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/d.log)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/e.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the list comes from dynamic listing of a remote file system you can use find, e.g.

```
- name: Get file name based on pattern
  find:
     paths: /tmp/test
     patterns: "*.log"
  register: find_results

- name: Download files log files, just as example about using find_result
  fetch: src="{{ item['path'] }}" dest="myLocalDir"
  with_items: "{{ find_results['files'] }}"
```

See [find - Return a list of files based on specific criteria](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html) for details.

To list files matching a pattern on the local machine see [fileglob](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/lookup/fileglob.html) instead.

If your list is not dynamically got from the file system but it's already done, use `match` or `search` [filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html)

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local   
  vars:
     myFiles:
          - /tmp/test/a.txt
          - /tmp/test/b.txt
          - /tmp/test/c.log
          - /tmp/test/d.log
          - /tmp/test/e.txt

  tasks:
     - name: Filter list
       set_fact:
          new_list: "{{ myFiles | select('match','^/tmp/test/.*..log$') | list }}"

     - name: Show filtered list
       debug: msg="{{ item }}"
       with_items: "{{ new_list }}"
```

Substitute accordingly `debug` with `file` module to remove your files.

Comment: Remote list no longer exist, and i don't want to search the entire directory and delete unwanted files, only files from the list that match the pattern are safe to delete

Comment: i have updated the question, i cant make my list work with your example

Comment: The example works by filtering a list. You didn't show the complete tasks of your playbook, neither set_fact and related select.